# SSIS Insert Data After Aggregate (Group By) with new Unique key

Tags: sql-server, ssis, group-by, aggregate

I have the Contoso Dataset of Microsoft. My goal is from this dataset which is a flat file, to fill tables on my database.
More specific the flat file contains three columns like these:

1. CurrencyLabel
2. CurrencyName
3. CurrencyDescription

My goal is to remove duplicates and insert the unique results in my table that have these columns
1. CurrencyKey
2. CurrencyLabel
3. CurrencyName
4. CurrencyDescription

The CurrencyKey column is the primary key of the table and it should be filled automatically with new keys of the results on SSIS.

At SSIS, i have made a control flow which contains the data flow.

In the data flow I have the flat file source, then aggregate with group by
with all columnns (CurrencyLabel, CurrencyName,CurrencyDescription ) and then I Have set the ole db destination to my table.

The goal is to fill all my four columns and the target is to increase the CurrencyKey from the aggregate.

The columns of the flat files and the first two rows:

```
OnlineSalesKey|SalesQuantity|SalesAmount|TotalCost|UnitCost|UnitPrice|CustomerLabel|Title|FirstName|MiddleName|LastName|BirthDate|MaritalStatus|Gender|EmailAddress|YearlyIncome|TotalChildren|NumberChildrenAtHome|Education|Occupation|HouseOwnerFlag|NumberCarsOwned|Phone|CurrencyLabel|CurrencyName|CurrencyDescription|IsWorkDay|IsHoliday|HolidayName|EuropeSeason|NorthAmericaSeason|AsiaSeason|ProductLabel|ProductName|ProductDescription|Manufacturer|BrandName|ColorName|Size|Weight|ProductCategoryLabel|ProductCategoryName|ProductCategoryDescription|StoreManager|StoreType|StoreName|StoreDescription|Status|OpenDate|CloseDate|StorePhone|StoreFax|Customer_address|store_address
19609697|1|313.52|180.22|180.22|391.9|18157||Isabella||Hall|1953-03-06|S|F|isabella80@adventure-works.com|90000|3|2|Partial College|Professional|1|1|1 (11) 500 555-0181|001|USD|US Dollar|WorkDay|0|None|Holiday|Spring/Back to Business|Holiday|0402095|Fabrikam SLR Camera M150 Orange|Digital camera ñ SLR, 5.2 in x 2.8 in x 3.7 in, 19.2 oz|Fabrikam, Inc.|Fabrikam|Orange|3.5 x 5 x 3.3 |5.25|04|Cameras and camcorders |Cameras and camcorders |246|Online|Contoso Europe Online Store|Contoso Europe Online Store|On|2004-09-03 00:00:00||731-555-0117|731-555-0117|Bundesallee 4422|Downtown Berlin, Germany
19609733|1|166.4|95.65|95.65|208|14866||Hailey|R|Peterson|1970-10-21|S|F|hailey14@adventure-works.com|40000|2|2|Partial College|Clerical|1|2|1 (11) 500 555-0123|001|USD|US Dollar|WorkDay|0|None|Holiday|Spring/Back to Business|Holiday|0504005|The Phone Company Smart phones 160x160 M26 Black|Smart phones 160x160, AC adapter, stylus, protective cover, installation CD-ROM, application manual|The Phone Company|The Phone Company|Black|4.5 x 3.1 x 0.6|4.5999999999999996|05|Cell phones|Cell phones|246|Online|Contoso Europe Online Store|Contoso Europe Online Store|On|2004-09-03 00:00:00||731-555-0117|731-555-0117|Pflugstr 24|Downtown Berlin, Germany
```

You can see that the fields are
001|USD|US Dollar 
1. CurrencyLabel
2. CurrencyName
3. CurrencyDescription

My table

[image: table]

My data flow

[image: dataflow]

Aggregate by group by

[image: aggregate]

Mappings on OLE DB DESTINATION

[image: mappings]

Right now nothing seems to be written in my table and there is error by this this output:

```
SSIS package 
Information: 0x4004300A at Fill Currency Table, SSIS.Pipeline: 
Validation phase is beginning.
Information: 0x4004300A at Fill Currency Table, SSIS.Pipeline: 
Validation phase is beginning.
Warning: 0x80049304 at Fill Currency Table, SSIS.Pipeline: Warning: 
Could not open global shared memory to communicate with performance 
DLL; data flow performance counters are not available.  To resolve, run 
this package as an administrator, or on the system's console.
Information: 0x40043006 at Fill Currency Table, SSIS.Pipeline: Prepare 
for Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x40043007 at Fill Currency Table, SSIS.Pipeline: Pre- 
Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x402090DC at Fill Currency Table, Flat File Source [30]: 
The processing of file "C:\Users\george\Desktop\Data_201813_10M.txt" 
has started.
Information: 0x4004300C at Fill Currency Table, SSIS.Pipeline: Execute 
phase is beginning.
Information: 0x402090DE at Fill Currency Table, Flat File Source [30]: 
The total number of data rows processed for file 
"C:\Users\george\Desktop\Data_201813_10M.txt" is 10000001.
Error: 0xC0202009 at Fill Currency Table, OLE DB Destination [102]: 
SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error 
code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native 
Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The statement has been 
terminated.".
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native 
Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Cannot insert the 
value NULL into column 'CurrencyKey', table 
'DataWarehouse.dbo.DimCurrency'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT 
fails.".
Error: 0xC0209029 at Fill Currency Table, OLE DB Destination [102]: 
SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "OLE DB 
Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" failed because error code 
0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "OLE DB 
Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" specifies failure on 
error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified 
component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more 
information about the failure.
Error: 0xC0047022 at Fill Currency Table, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error 
Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component 
"OLE DB Destination" (102) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while 
 processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (115). The identified 
component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is 
specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the 
Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted 
before this with more information about the failure.
Information: 0x40043008 at Fill Currency Table, SSIS.Pipeline: Post 
Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x402090DD at Fill Currency Table, Flat File Source [30]: 
The processing of file "C:\Users\george\Desktop\Data_201813_10M.txt" 
has ended.
Information: 0x4004300B at Fill Currency Table, SSIS.Pipeline: "OLE DB 
Destination" wrote 1 rows.
Information: 0x40043009 at Fill Currency Table, SSIS.Pipeline: Cleanup 
phase is beginning.
Task failed: Fill Currency Table
Warning: 0x80019002 at DataWarehouse2018: SSIS Warning Code 
DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but 
the number of errors raised (3) reached the maximum allowed (1); 
resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the 
number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or 
fix the errors.
SSIS package
```

Any idea?

Thank you

Comment: Are any of the columns `CurrencyLabel`,`CurrencyName` and `CurrencyDescription` set to `NOT NULL`? If so, there's 1 reason. Otherwise, is the value of `CurrencyKey` being populated? The actual error will tell you what column is the problem.

Comment: @Larnu All the columns of the table does not allow null values. The point is to remove the duplicates and insert the unique rows in my table with unique ids to CurrencyKey. How to see if CurrencyKey is populated?Thank you very much

Comment: Well, considering that it's not in your flat file, that would suggest it isn't, unless you're doing something that you haven't told us. And if all the columns are set to`NOT NULL` are you *sure* that none of your data has`NULL` values?

Comment: I changed in my table to NOT NULL the columns of table except the CurrencyKey. The aggregate and ole db destination completed successfully  with message one row wrote but i see in table and it is empty. I attach screenshots

Comment: If the row is empty (I assume you mean contained `NULL`s, which isn't the same as empty), then you the columns had no value when you imported them.

Comment: No no it does not contain NULLs. It is really Empty. And the columns cannot be empty because I use the Microsoft`s dataset, the Contoso.

Comment: So the value is `''`? We really need to be able to replicate the issue you have, but all we have are vague descriptions (not even sample data). I suggest taking a step back and working out if you could answer this question as it is. We need more information now, as I'm out of guesses.

Comment: Yes the value is ' '. I will try to edit the answer againg.

Comment: @Larnu I edited my question

Comment: It doesn't appear you've added any detail though. *"We really need to be able to replicate the issue you have"*; considering I have no idea what your data or dataflow looks like that is impossible.

Comment: @Larnu please check now

Comment: So you're aggregating 10,000,000 rows into 1 row? Why? If every value is the same, why not just use the value(s) of the first row? Have you inspected the values between the aggregate component and the destination component?

Comment: This is the first task I have to do. Then I will continue with DimStore,DimCustomer,DimProduct and so on. But the process will be the same for all of them. And yes my output for the currency should be indeed one row. But it fails.